# Java Modulo creating wrong results (with examples)?

Tags: java, modulo

i try to calculate whether the single dosages of a therapy are in accordance with the total dosage.

I created a little java tool.

For this i included a small check:

```
System.out.println(total);
System.out.println(single);
System.out.println(total % single);
if(total % single == 0.0) {
System.out.println("test");
}
```

Now. Here are a coule of results for some of my data points. And i just dont understand it:

Two examples where it works as intended.

```
Total: 60
Single: 7.5
Result: 0.0

Total: 30.0
Single: 3.0
Result: 0.0
```

Modulo gives out wrong results? Shouldnt it also be 0.0?

```
Total: 37.0
Single: 3.7
Result: 3.6999999999999984
```

Any explanations for this?

Comment: Are gesamt and einzel supposed to be total and single?

Comment: And `40 % 13.5` *is* 13. What's the problem?

Comment: `40` is `(2 * 13.5) + 13` , you have the expected result of modulo .

Comment: The last result is likely due to double precision

Comment: Ahh ye exactly, i translated it into english. Ok and your right about the 40%13.5. Those are exactly the cases i want to find. But the last case with 37.0 and 3.7. Shouldnt it be 0.0? What is this double precision your talking about? Isnt modulo wrong in this case?

Comment: Best to check if it's within a small value of the goal, so in this case you could check `37.0 % 3.7 < 0.001 || 37.0 % 3.7 > 3.699`

Comment: @Carcigenicate On java 1.8.0_161, `System.out.println(37.0 % 3.7);` prints `3.6999999999999984`

Comment: @phflack The result should be `0`, so it's off by `3.6999999999999984`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp But in the realm of mod, it's actually off by `0.0000000000000016`